# a function to calculate the OLS intercept and slope

Tags: variables, regression, linear-regression

```
OLS = function(x,y){
slope = cov(x, y)/var(x)
intercept = mean(y) - (slope*mean(x))
return(c(slope,intercept))
}
```

I want to write a calculate the OLS intercept and slope for a given predictor and outcome. I write the code as above. But when I use it,it just gives me a bunch of NAs.I think the problem is in the (x,y). Maybe I should not use x and y as I will plug in random variables.

Comment: Break it down. Does cov(x,y) return NA? Does var(x) return NA or zero?

Comment: I got it, the function is right, my other part of code went wrong.